# Find the Cramer-Rao bound for an unbiased estimator of $b^2$

Tags: probability, statistics

$X$ is a RV with pdf $f(x,b) = \frac{x}{b^2} \exp \{-\frac{x^2}{2b^2} \}$

I've got two different estimates: $\hat{b^2} =\frac{2}{\pi} (\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n X_i)^2 $ using MME, and $\hat{b^2} = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n X_i^2$ using MLE. MLE is generally considered unbiased, right? So I'll go with that.

The Cramer-Rao bound is defined as $\mathbb{E}[T(X)-g(b)]^2 \ge \frac{(g'(b))^2}{J(b)}$ where $J(b)$ is the Fisher information and $g(b) = \mathbb{E}T(X) =\int_0^{\infty} T(x) \frac{x}{b^2} \exp \{-\frac{x^2}{2b^2} \} dx$.

Of course, $T(X)$ is the estimate : $T(X)=\hat{b^2} = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n X_i^2$.

I've got $J(b) = \frac{4}{b^2}$ for the Fisher info (God, the calculations are a pain!) and now I'm a little unsure whether I'm proceeding correctly to compute the $g'(b)$.

\begin{align}
g'(b) &=\frac{\partial}{\partial b}\int_0^{\infty} \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2 \frac{x_i}{b^2} \exp \{-\frac{x_i^2}{2b^2} \} dx\\
&=\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n \int_0^{\infty}\Bigg(\frac{-2x^3}{b^3}+\frac{x^5}{b^5} \Bigg) e^{-\frac{x_i^2}{2b^2} } dx\\
&= 4b\\
\end{align}

is the setup correct?

This way my ultimate answer for the CRB would be $\mathbb{E}[T(X)-g(b)]^2 \ge 4b^4$.

Thanks for any help. Also : unless you really love calculus, I suggest you use Wolframalpha ;-)

Comment: I didn't check the details, but if $g(b) = b^2, g^{\prime} = 2b$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One can check one's work on such things with a computer algebra system. For this problem, you have a random variable $X$ ~ Rayleigh($b$) with pdf $f(x)$:

[image]
<sub>(source: [tri.org.au](http://www.tri.org.au/se/rayleighpdf.png))</sub>

Then, for random samples of size $n$ drawn on $X$, the CRLB for all unbiased estimators of $b^2$ is:

$$\text{CRLB}=\frac{1}{n *\text{FisherInformation}\left[b ^2,f\right]}$$

where `FisherInformation` is a mathStatica funkeh monkeh, and $f$ is the pdf. Here we go:

[image]
<sub>(source: [tri.org.au](http://www.tri.org.au/se/rayleighfish2.png))</sub>

---

Alternatively, since you have correctly derived yourself that the Fisher Information on $b$ (rather than $b^2$) is: 
$$J(b) = \frac{4}{b^2}$$

and if $g(b)$ is some differentiable function of $b$ that we are interested in estimating, then, subject to some regularity conditions, the CRLB on $g(b)$ is:

$$\left(\frac{\partial g(b) }{\partial b }\right)^2 \frac{1}{n J(b)} $$

In your case, $g(b)=b^2$ ... so after differentiating, you get the same result $\frac{b^4}{n}$ .

---

P.S. Your title should be:  CRLB for an unbiased *estimator* of $b^2$  ...not *estimate*

Comment: wait, I don't have to compute the integral for $g(b)$ the way I did? I can just say that since the estimator is unbiased, $g(b)=b^2$ must be true, right? Wow. So much unnecessary work...

Comment: Yes - lots of unnecessary work up there :) All you need is $J(b)$ and since $g(b)= b^2$, it follows immediately that $g'(b) = 2b$